# Where is the setting to control compilation of .ts test files

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have two separate Typescript projects in VS Code. Both have a folder named `test` in `\src`. Both projects have the same jest.config.js. One project does not compiles the .ts files under `test` but one does and saves them to the `outDir` folder.

Where is the setting that controls the compilation of test .ts files?

The project that does not compile the test .ts files are running the tests without issue. How does jest work under the hood? Doesn't it require the js files in order to run tests?

Comment: you can control the compilation via include/exclude keys in tsconfig.json file. No it does not require js file to run the test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest does not require js files to run the test cases. You can control the compilation of .ts files from the tsconfig.json files of both projects. Just include only relevant directory paths of source code only so that each compiles and place only .js of actual code to respective outDir.

Comment: So, in test files, I can use import paths that are meaningful only to the .ts file itself?

Comment: yes, writing code in .test.ts files will be same as you write for .ts actual code files.